# Gradle dynamic flavor

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-productflavors

I would like to create dynamic flavors from the directory tree. 
It works great!

But Android Studio uses gradle in its tmp file like:

> /home/svirch_n/.IntelliJIdea14/system/compile-server

and my script doesn't work anymore because it uses relative paths like this:

```
Closure getFlavors = { rootDir, basePackage ->
    def result = [:]
    new File("$rootDir").eachDir() { dir ->
        def name = dir.getName()
            if ("$name" != "main")
                result.put("$name", "$basePackage.$name")
        }
    return result
}

// This is an ugly closure.
// If I can get rid of this, my problem will be solved
Closure getSrcPath = {
    if (System.getProperty("user.dir").split("/").last() == "app") {
        return "src"
    } else {
        return "app/src"
    }
}

android {

    ...

    def myFlavors = getFlavors(getSrcPath(), "com.example.app")

    productFlavors {

        myFlavors.each { flavorName, flavorPackage ->
            "$flavorName" {
                applicationId "$flavorPackage"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help

P.S: I want dynamic flavors cause my git project has public and private repositories and not everyone can have all the flavors but I want them to compile anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am in the subproject 'app', I can use:

```
project(":app").getProjectDir().getPath()
```