# Lifecycle Android plugin gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am looking for a way to include flavors dynamically

To do so, I try to include subproject with attributes to configure the main Android project.
Here is my example:

```
app
|-> src
|    |-> flavor
|           |-> build.gradle
|-> build.gradle
|-> settings.gradle
```

app/settings.gradle

```
include ':src:flavor'
```

app/src/flavor/build.gradle

```
ext {
    isFlavor = true
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
...

android {

    ...

    productFlavors {

        getAllprojects().each { project ->
            if (project.ext.has("isFlavor")) {
                def name = project.getName()
                "$name" {
                    applicationId "com.example.app.$name"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This looks amazing.. But it doesn't work!
Because Android is configured before gradle checks the subprojects and flavor.ext.isFlavor doesn't exists yet.
And if I use configuration injection, Android spit on my face that I wouldn't dare!

```
Android tasks have already been created
```

I have read on stackoverflow that I have to create my attributes in my rootProject and configure Android in each subprojects.

But in my case subprojects aren't projects but flavors..

Does anyone has an idea to configure attribute in subprojects and uses them in the rootProject ?

I search near the `apply from:` feature right now..

P.S: Here is my main thread with an other solution: [Gradle dynamic flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323085/gradle-dynamic-flavor)

Comment: It is not so clear your request. You can configure the flavor with the build.gradle in app folder, not using another build.gradle inside the flavor.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have updated my post. I am trying to add flavors dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a conditional and `apply from:` to force the lifecycle to apply my values:

```
if (new File(project(":app").getProjectDir().getPath() + "/flavors.gradle").exists()) {
    apply from: "flavors.gradle"
}
```